# How should a large solution (20+ projects) be broken up?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, project-organization

I have a large solution with 20+ projects. Most of them are utility-type projects that perform a specific, discreet, defined set of functionality with no dependencies on the domain-specific projects.

This solution is checked into Github.

I now need to make a new solution and I need to use 2 or 3 of the projects from the original large solution. How should I go about breaking those projects out of the large solution and making them available to both solutions that need them?

What is the typical way to do this? Best practices?

I'm having a hard time picturing this so some practical tips, pratices, and maybe even a step by step would be useful.

Comment: Close voter? Seriously? Bored tonight?

Comment: There are many approaches you could take here, each with their pros and cons, which makes it hard to provide a specific answer for your scenario and makes the question "broad" and "opinion based". Some suggestions: look at moving your common components to your own NuGet packages (is actually fiarly easy); have a CommonBinary solution and use deployed binaries and the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Large solution? How about >100-project solution? This question can be classified as "too broad" and "opinion-based". Nevertheless, since I am a build master, I will give you few tips.

If you can identify "core" projects, put them into one solution and build them to `bin` while referencing from DLLs from same `bin`

> `--Solution1
>     --bin
>     --Proj1
>     --Proj2
>     --Products
>       --Prod1
>         --Prod1Solution
>         --Proj3
>         --Proj4
>       --Prod2
>         --Prod2Solution
>         --Proj5
>         --Proj6
>     ...`

Now, you may have your "End product projects", like products that make use of some core assemblies. These "products" should reside under same branch as Solution1 above, may be under different folder. You create a solution for each of your product and if it is small, you can even use project references but you still reference DLLs from `bin`. And you can build it, for example under `bin\Product1`.

Another option - to have one grand solution with solution folders and build entire set together.

We use first option because this allows for highly customized builds. I can build base set of projects and distribute to devs who write custom solutions. Or I can build entire set with core products in it.